# How to Update the Song Information When Casting Continuous Audio Streams

Tags: android, google-cast

I have a continuous audio stream since I'm casting from my Internet radio application. How can I update the song information?

Do I need to create a custom receiver that updates the information?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you do need to write a custom receiver to handle that; neither the Default nor the Styled receiver can do that for you.

Comment: OK, so I guess I don't need to do anything with the MediaInfo object which cannot be updated. How will I be sending the information to the receiver application?